# Bad idea to use Sequelize to validate non-database objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I'm already using Sequelize as my ORM, and I love using the powerful built-in model validation. I am considering using Sequelize as a schema validator in certain situations where there wouldn't be any actual database writes. In other words, I would never call `.save()`, on the model, but I would call `.validate()` to validate the model.

Do I need to do anything special to prevent sequelize from creating a table? Is there a good reason not to do this and use something like `express-validator` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I wouldn't do that if I were you. The problem in my opinion is that first it is very confusing for anyone (even yourself in long run) to determine whether if the model is a database table or not.

Secondly it creates an unnecessary dependency where it is not needed and forces you to even change non-database models too if you ever decide to change your ORM to something else.

Also there is a little chance to mistakenly executing `save()` method.

I'd suggest you to use packages like `Joi` and `class-validator` instead.